# Angular2 material datepicker inline

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am using Angular 2 Material Date-picker in my project. How can I show inline date-picker ?

Reference - 
https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker

Please let me know is it can be done using angular material (md-datepicker).

Comment: please update the code you have tried in the question

Comment: What do you mean by "inline"?

Comment: It will be open by default.

Comment: I too require this, Inline he meant is to show a standalone datepicker rather than a popup

Comment: @AbhiPavithran other option is to create custom datepicker by using momentjs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `md-calendar` component this way for this instead of the `md-datepicker` one:

```
<mat-calendar (selectedChange)="onCalendarSelectedChange($event)">
</mat-calendar>
```